# Who could streamline this script better than what it is?, regarding mostly those tmp's

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, audio-streaming

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# Usage:
#   ytpl song title
#   ytpl < titles
#

go() {
    echo "Playing $1"

    # Force TTY input for controls even if titles are read from input
    echo https://youtu.be/ > tmp1.txt
    youtube-dl --get-id "ytsearch:$1" > tmp2.txt
    youtube-dl --get-title "ytsearch:$1" > tmp4.txt
    paste -d" " tmp1.txt tmp2.txt > tmp3.txt
    paste -d" " tmp3.txt tmp4.txt > tmp5.txt
    sed 's/ //' tmp5.txt > tmp6.txt
    cat tmp6.txt
    mpv --vid=no "$(youtube-dl -g "ytsearch:$1" | tail -1)" < /dev/tty
    rm tmp*.txt
}

# All arguments as a single space separated string
if [ -n "$*" ]; then
    go "$*"
    exit
fi

# Read one title per line
while read title; do
    go "$title"
done
```

Comment: You are supposed to accept the answer (by clicking on the V-shaped symbol next to the answer text) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Oops, I did not see this message yesterday sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo https://youtu.be/ > tmp1.txt
youtube-dl --get-id "ytsearch:$1" >> tmp1.txt
youtube-dl --get-title "ytsearch:$1" >> tmp1.txt
cat tmp1.txt |tr '\n' ' '|sed 's/ //' > tmp2.txt
cat tmp2.txt
mpv --vid=no "$(youtube-dl -g "ytsearch:$1" | tail -1)" < /dev/tty
rm tmp*.txt
```

Code sample 2 
Follow these many instructions:
http://www.unixmen.com/access-twitter-via-command-line-terminal/

```
a=$(youtube-dl --get-id "ytsearch:$1")
b=$(youtube-dl --get-title "ytsearch:$1")
c="https://youtu.be/$a $b"
echo $c
t update "$c"
mpv --vid=no "$(youtube-dl -g "ytsearch:$1" | tail -1)" < /dev/tty
```

Comment: I need those 3 lines straight into 1 so I could use it to paste into a list and/or share it to Facebook and Twitter, opening the browser from the terminal itself :) THX

Comment: @user3287029 There 3 lines into 1

Comment: That! Sir... did it :) THX

Comment: @user3287029  FYI:  --get-id and --get-title can be combined in 1 line, but they will be in the reverse order. **youtube-dl  --get-id --get-title "ytsearch:$1"**.

Comment: I know that's why I had to separate them, sorry one more request, the first blankspace needs to be deleted and join the "youtu.be/" with the --get-id result. :(

Comment: @user3287029 updated answer

Comment: How can I use cURL to send the youtube link to twitter with the Twitter Api (I'm  guessing) all in one line preferably or calling another bash. I know it is too much to ask. THX

Comment: See if code sample #2 works

Comment: You are incredible :) is almost working. But they said Twitter does not allow it this way anymore, perhaps I can use Twurl for that.

Comment: @user3287029  updated again.  Follow the instructions from unixmen.com, and my then my script change.

Comment: No I don't need another idea.  I optimized your script, and gave you 2 modifications, so I would rather have my answer marked as the correct answer.  You want something else you will have to post a new question, for someone else to answer.